# How to Search for a related records in textfields when search is to be done from two tables in PHP with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables One is registration and the other is user table:
I want to search records from both the tables, i can search the record from one table 
by the step given below but did not know at the same time some text fiels are there in my 
form which should match with the records in the database i.e. name and address are comming from the other tables.

```
<?

  $gender=$_POST['GENDER'];
  $age=$_POST['AGE'];
  $Religion=$_POST['RELIGION'];

  $name=$_POST['NAME'];
  $address=$_POST['ADDRESS'];

 $sql = mysql_query("select * from registration where `religion` LIKE '%".$Religion."%' AND `age` LIKE '%".$age."%' AND `gender` LIKE '%".$gender."%'") or die(mysql_error());

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 ---
 --
 }
```

My Table Description is as follows:

```
Registration Table:
Userid
Gender
Age
Religion

User Table:
uid
name
address
```

Comment: Your SQL is in a potentially dangerous form, it is vulnerable to SQL injection, you might want to read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Thanks.. for your suggestion can you let me know how can i solve my above problem, i have various dropdowns and textboxes and want to show records which matches from both the tables because some records will be searched from user table and some from registration.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UNION` -

```
$sql = "(SELECT * FROM registration WHERE 
         `religion` LIKE '%".$Religion."%' AND
         `age` LIKE '%".$age."%' AND 
         `gender` LIKE '%".$gender."%')  UNION

        (SELECT * FROM user WHERE 
         `name` LIKE '%".$name."%' AND 
         `address` LIKE '%".$address."%')";
```

**ADVICE:** Avoid using `mysql_*` functions since it is deprecated. Learn `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: Thanks.. I have tried the following query but it is not returning any row :  $sql = mysql_query("(select * from registration where `religion` LIKE '%".$Religion."%' AND `gender` LIKE '%".$genders."%' AND `Age` LIKE '%".$age."%') UNION (SELECT * FROM user WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$name."%')");

Comment: Is there any problem in syntax.

Comment: I don't think so. Syntax seems fine. Your solution is `UNION`

Comment: No records are being searched and displayed,even though i am selecting those records which are in database.